# Swift UIAlertController fire once per row select textfield edited

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I have a UIPickerView with an if statement in selectedRowInComponent that checks the value of a textField. If the user inputed number in the textfield is greater than 10, an alert is called. All is working well except I'd like to have the alert only fire a single time after the row is selected and the field is edited. As it stands, the alert is called every time the field is updated/edited with a value greater than 10. The initial alert is sufficient. Any tips on how I can accomplish this? Thanks!

```
if (inputField.text! as NSString).doubleValue > 10 {

                SweetAlert().showAlert("Number is greater than 10", subTitle: "Please select number less than 10", style: AlertStyle.CustomImag(imageFile: "alertimage.png"))
            }
```

Comment: bro i know answer but answer in objective c so wait i will find in swift

Comment: Appreciate the help!

Comment: convert this code in swift  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification* notification){
        [message dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and Dirty:

Create a bool variable publicly available in your viewController and initialize it with false (lets call the variable 'alertAlreadyShown')

Then just make an if statement about that bool in your pickerView method

```
       if (inputField.text! as NSString).doubleValue > 10 {
            if (alertAlreadyShown == false) {
                    SweetAlert().showAlert(...)
                    alertAlreadyShown = true
            }
       }
```

But don't forget to reset the bool at appropriate times to enable the alert again

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you could go about this. One would be (and the most user friendly in my opinion) only show values of less than ten in your picker view. The other option would be to set a bool for whether or not the alert had been displayed, and add that as a check to your if statement.

Comment: Hello @pbush25 the boolean option sounds like it would be the better of the two options for my situation.  The pickerView is selecting products represented as constants in my code. The textField is the input value for a variable used in my calculations.

Comment: How would I go about converting my alert to bool?